# Which is more basic: aniline or pyridine?

Tags: organic-chemistry, acid-base

Please explain why, thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You can look at the pKb values.  It turns out pyridine is more basic.  This is difficult to predict from looking at the Lewis structures of the molecules.  What you should see is that the lone pair on pyridine is on an sp2 hybridized N.  This makes it less basic than an sp3 N.  The N in aniline is sp3 but the lone pair is in resonance with the pi electrons of the phenyl ring, lowering the basicity.